# Not able to connect to remote VM on linux machine

Tags: linux, networking

I have developed an application in golang which is starting on 127.0.0.11:5051 of 101.45.41.78 linux machine. I want to call a **GET ** rest endpoint of this application from 101.45.41.85 i.e. another linux machine. I am making a curl request like curl 101.45.41.78:5051/test/helloWorld. But I am getting below error Failed to connect to 101.45.41.78 port 5051: Connection refused. I am new to both golang and linux. Can someone please help me how to resolve or debug this ?

Curl Request should return hello world response.

Comment: If you are binding to the loopback IP `127.0.0.1`, the server will only accept connections from that interface - so from localhost. Try binding to `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces)

Comment: All IP addresses in 127.0.0. *n* are assigned to the NIC and are never available over a network. They are distinct, however, so one can have 255 servers on one machine, available *only* from that one machine, or if connected remotely (e.g., Remote Desktop).

Comment: Thank you @gronostaj, DrMoishe Pippik. After reading your comments I changed the IP to 101.45.41.85 from 127.0.0.11. It's working now. I will have to explore a bit about IP binding.